# Graph of Landsat Downloads?

Tags: data-request, data.gov, uses-of-open-data

Where can I find find a graph of Landsat downloads, to show the effect free access has had?

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, here:

[image]

Source: http://www.usgs.gov/blogs/features/files/2015/01/free-and-open-data-policy-graph-no-footnote.jpg

Here is the original post, noting cost savings from Landsat. http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/?p=9654

Comment: If you're happy with the answer, please go ahead and accept it :)

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I actually have to wait two days though. Just trying to spread some good news.  :)

Comment: Thanks for posting this @Dan. It is indeed some good news.