# Public Website statistics

Tags: data-request

Do you know websites (other than Wikimedia) that provide page views statistics ? I found stats about Wiki, but I would like to retrieve data from another website.

Answer (score 4):

u.s. city open data census tracks analytics offered by cities
http://us-city.census.okfn.org/

EDIT:
the epa lists analytics of some sort, and has over a decades worth here:
http://www.epa.gov/reports/objects/emfjulte/

EDIT 2:
Pennsylvania Spatial Data Access (PASDA) is PA's gis clearinghouse and offers great stats datasets covering almost a decade.  here's an example:
http://www.pasda.psu.edu/about/publications/PASDAStatistics_20140101-20141231.pdf
you can snag them here:
http://www.pasda.psu.edu/about/publications.asp

EDIT 3:
usgs landsat recently published some data regarding their data use; the post is more about the economic benefits of open data, however there's a really cool chart about data usage stats over time. hat tip to @dan for answering his question here:
[Graph of Landsat Downloads?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4370/graph-of-landsat-downloads)
you can read the report and view the chart here:
http://landsat.gsfc.nasa.gov/?p=9654

EDIT 4:
A.C.I.S. SEARCH TOOL - Animal Care Information System Search Tool shares some of its visitors statistics, which were much higher than i thought they would be, based off the tools design and functionality. but there's roughly 14000 days of data here:
via:
https://acissearch.aphis.usda.gov/LPASearch/faces/CustomerSearch.jspx;jsessionid=7f00000130d77a076f42228f4753ad1492029f4879f5.e38Obx8Sb3yQby0Qa3mQe0

EDIT 5:
analytics.usa.gov is a dashboard for analytics across dotgov sites:
https://analytics.usa.gov/

Philadelphia's site:
http://analytics.phila.gov/

Answer (score 3):

[LinuxFR](http://linuxfr.org/), one of the most popular tech news websites in France, makes all of its web statistics public:

http://linuxfr.org/webalizer/

About 1 million visits per month on average.

[image: LinuxFR stats]

For each month, a lot of data is available: see for instance http://linuxfr.org/webalizer/usage_201501.html

Answer (score 1):

You can often find this information by searching for signatures of reports generaed by website reporting tools, and removing instances of the distributing website.

For example:

- [webalizer](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=webalizer+-site%3Awebalizer.org%2F+%22Usage+statistics+for%22)
- [analog](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=analog+%22Web+Server+Statistics+for%22+%22Analyzed+requests+from%22)
- [awstats](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Created+by+awstats%22+%22Not+viewed+traffic+includes+traffic+generated+by+robots,+worms,+or+replies+with+special+HTTP+status+codes.%22)

For a list of more web analysis tools, see [AlternativeTo](http://alternativeto.net/software/analog/)

The licensing might be questionable, but as these are data extracted using generic search tools, I don't believe that the data in them would be copyrightable.  If that isn't good enough assurance for you, you can filter by US government websites.